# Saving the current state of the PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I have a `ViewPager` that I would like to save a current state once leaving an `Activity`. One of my option is to save the current variables values in a database that I already have and read them back when recreated the activity. However this solution seems to be overworked. Is there another, better way to recover the last state of the `ViewPagwer`? Can I use those two methods of the `ViewPager` adapter?

```
@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
```

If so please provide simple example of using it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is really depended on what kind of data you want to save. If it is some private fields, you might use these 2 methods and Parcelable if data is more complex. Usually it is not required to use DB for this purpose, use DB as a cache if you catch data from internet or somewhere else and want to save/restore it not to reload again after destroying an activity, but it is different question. So, to cache data you need to use DB and files folder of app right after you downloaded all needed data from internet, then use AsyncTaskLoader to load it from DB and then use PagerAdapter to represent it on ViewPager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On each page I display different content that changes depending on action that has been taken. It's mostly different text on the text view and different background. How can I display this particular content for this particular page and set the pager to the position I have left, after activity it recreated?

Comment: In Fragment or Activity where you have ViewPager, you can use onSaveInstancestate and onRestoreInstanceState to get and save and then restore any temporary values of UI, like positions.

Comment: ok. How about those two methods that I have mentioned about? They are inside the PagerAdapter of my ViewPager.